# turing back to developer-mode error magento2

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I don't know how to fix this and I have an idea what might caused it. Here is what happened

I went on **production mode**. On production mode everything works fine. But when I try to go back to **developer mode** I get a **warning** on browser.
**To change to developer mode** I did this

```
rm -rf generated/code generated/metadata
```

and

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Here is the error I get when I try to check the website.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: file_put_contents(/chroot/home/.../.../html/pub/static/frontend/presiden/presiden_fashion_home2/el_GR/css/style.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php on line 177

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: file_put_contents(/chroot/home/.../.../html/pub/static/frontend/presiden/presiden_fashion_home2/el_GR/css/style.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php on line 177
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/chroot/home/br...', 177, Array)
#1 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php(177): file_put_contents('/chroot/home/br...', '@-webkit-keyfra...')
#2 /chroot/home/.../.../html/app/code/Plazathemes/Layout/Block/Layout.php(43): lessc->compileFile('/chroot/home/br...', '/chroot/home/br...')
#3 /chroot/home/.../.../html/app/design/frontend/presiden/presiden_fashion_default/Plazathemes_Layout/templates/html/header.phtml(1): Plazathemes\Layout\Block\Layout->renderFileLessToCss()
#4 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/chroot/home/br...')
#5 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Plazathemes\Layout\Block\Layout), '/chroot/home/br...', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/chroot/home/br...')
#7 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#8 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#9 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(533): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('custom_header')
#10 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('custom_header')
#11 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('custom_header')
#12 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('custom_header', false)
#13 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('custom_header', false)
#14 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#15 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#16 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#17 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#18 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(535): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#20 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#21 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(488): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#22 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#23 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#24 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#25 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#26 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#27 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#28 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#29 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#30 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#31 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#32 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#33 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#34 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#35 /chroot/home/.../.../html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#36 /chroot/home/.../.../html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#37 /chroot/home/.../.../html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#38 {main}
```

Can this be because I changed the sizes of an image in `/chroot/home/.../.../html/pub/static/frontend/presiden/presiden_fashion_home2/el_GR/css/style.css` 
this file? How can I fix this ? Any idea?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy el_GR** for your specific locale, because M2 by default generates for en_US.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this givin chmod -R 777 in pub/static/
and rm -rf generated/

Comment: Smaller line are writing on comment section .